# full-bleed images above posting under google+ on ios

Tags: html, ios, iphone, google-plus

Within the google+ app on ios the cards with links to photo pages on my website are shown as a small thumbnail with text next to it.

Under android and on the web things work as should: A full-bleed image above the text.

The 3 open graph headers which are needed are available in the linked page, so I'm a bit lost why the ios app doesn't show the full-bleed image. Especially since the ios app was supposed to be the first to get this feature.

Am I missing a necessary header? or is it an google+ for IOS issue?

[My google+ collection with links to images](https://plus.google.com/u/0/collection/0hgD2)

[A page on my website containing the og: headers](http://funsite.eu/2015/09/bridge/)

This is **only** a problem in google+ under IOS.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's working on Android and web but not iOS, than it's probably a bug on Google's side.

Comment: Guess so. but while doing research I found that this feature was first on ios, lots of apple users were happy. If it stopped working since I would expect to find complains too..